# How to use width() to change the width of an image?

Tags: jquery, width

I've looked around SO and the interwebs but have been unable to locate a clear answer. This is a newbie jQuery question.  :)

How do I use .width() to get the width of a div, say #imgwrap, and output that width in an img src... I'm using Automattic's Jetpack to dynamically resize images.

Thanks!

`<img src="http://i2.wp.com/google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif?resize=[widthgoeshere],205" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most getters in jQuery have a paired setter. The difference between the two are whether you supply an argument. In the case of width you can supply a width argument if you wish to set it

```
 var divWidth = $('#myDivID').width();
 $('#imageID').width(divWidth);
```

**EDIT**
Ok following the comment you'd simply have to set the src attribute instead.
You can set any attribute using the `attr(attributeName,value)` method

in your case attributeName would be `'src'` and value be the ùrl`from the below examplethat would be something like

```
 var divWidth = $('#myDivID').width(),
     url = "http://i2.wp.com/google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif?resize=" + divWidth + ",205";
 $('#imageID').attr('src', url);
```

Comment: What is the best way to output the `var divWidth` into the actual src so the re-sizing can be done on the server? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("img").attr("src","http://i2.wp.com/google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif?resize="+jQuery("#imgwrap").width()+",205");
```

Comment: what is the best way to get your syntax to show on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
var divWidth = $('#myDivID').width();
$('#imageID').css('width',divWidth);
```

should work